# Cannot connect to sql server using pyodbc

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, database, pyodbc

I'm unable to connect to SQL-server using pyodbc module in python, my connection string is like this.

```
pyodbc.connect(driver=driv,host=server,database=db,trusted_connection="yes",user=user,password=pasw)
```

I'm hitting an error like this

> Error: ('28000', '[28000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication. (18452) (SQLDriverConnect); [28000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication. (18452)')

The version of sql server I'm having is,

> Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP1) - 11.0.3000.0 (X64)   Oct 19 2012
>   13:38:57   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition
>   (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2  (Build 9200: )

which I had got by running **SELECT @@VERSION** query.
I had used SQL Server Native Client 11.0 as driver. One thing I noticed is that in sql server management studio I used SQL server authentication instead of windows authentication. But here, by the error message it seems it is trying windows authentication instead. Is there any way I can use SQL server authentication instead of windows authentication here? I guess that would solve this problem.

Answer (score 4):

With the more recent versions of Microsoft's ODBC driver for SQL Server, `Trusted_Connection=yes` takes precedence, so the connection will attempt to use Windows authentication even if `UID=` and `PWD=` are supplied. If you want to use SQL Server authentication then simply use `Trusted_Connection=no` and supply the `UID=` and `PWD=` for the SQL Server login.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to connect to it from another domain controller then you will get this error when *IntegratedSecurity = True*, by default

Integrated security means simply - use your windows credentials for login verification to SQL Server. So, if you are logged in to a different domain controller then it will fail. In the case where you are on two different domain controllers then you have no choice but to use
*IntegratedSecurity = false*

So you can try this:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect(
                      r'DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};
                      SERVER=localhost;
                      Integrated_Security=false;
                      Trusted_Connection=yes;
                      UID=user;
                      PWD=password;
                      DATABASE= db')
```